# How to insert a title after a paragraph using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to insert a title after a paragraph using python-docx. To do so, I have this first function that allows me to insert any element after a paragraph :

```
def insert_element_after_paragraph(element, paragraph):
    p = paragraph._p
    p.addnext(element)
```

And then using this function I am trying to insert a title :

```
paraIndex = 20   #Position of my paragraph
personPara = document.add_heading(f"Title {i+1} :", 2)
personHeadungPara = insert_element_after_paragraph(personPara._p, document.paragraphs[paraIndex])
```

But by doing this, it will not add a title but a paragraph.

So how can I correct this to have a title inserted and not a paragraph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what happens when you call: `personPara = document.add_heading(f"Title {i+1} :", 2)` is that a new heading will be added to the bottom of the document storing the reference to it. in your case, you don't want to add the new heading to the bottom of the document, but rather to insert it at the given position.

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document()

h1 = doc.add_heading('Test heading 1')
p1 = doc.add_paragraph('text of para 1')
p2 = doc.add_paragraph('text of para 2')

p2.insert_paragraph_before(text='Test heading 2', style='Heading 1')

doc.save('test.docx')
```

> So how can I correct this to have a title inserted and not a paragraph?

note that title is actually a `paragraph` with a `Heading` style applied to it.

[image: word preview after inserted heading title]

Comment: i actually now tried your example from above, and it works as expected for me. `insert_element_after_paragraph` doesn't return anything so `personHeadungPara` will always be `None`. can you elaborate your question? in my answer, i though that it would be handy to use the existing `insert_paragraph_before` by picking a different insertion point.  you can always use `_element.getnext()` to get the next element in the doc if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`docx` package now named as `python-docx` from the same author Steve Canny.

https://pypi.org/project/docx/
https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/

`python-docx` got more recent updates